# Eigen library, simple linear algebra operations with sparse matrices increasing their allocated size

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I am relatively new to Eigen, and am facing the following issue when using sparse matrices in Eigen.

When I use the below code, the allocatedsize for the variable C increases to 20 after addition. I am lost as to why is this happening.

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix< double > A( 10, 1 );
A.reserve( Eigen::VectorXi::Constant(1,3) );

A.coeffRef( 2, 0 ) = 2;
A.coeffRef( 3, 0 ) = 3;
A.coeffRef( 7, 0 ) = 7;

Eigen::SparseMatrix< double > B( 10, 1 );
B.reserve( Eigen::VectorXi::Constant(1,3) );

B.coeffRef( 0, 0 ) = 0;
B.coeffRef( 1, 0 ) = 1;
B.coeffRef( 8, 0 ) = 8;

Eigen::SparseMatrix< double > C( 10, 1 );
C.reserve( Eigen::VectorXi::Constant(1,6) );

C = A + B;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in [`assign_sparse_to_sparse`](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/2b969e50885e26f0ca909ebb2b0263cd9c649bd6/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseAssign.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#SparseAssign.h-110) there is a line

```
temp.reserve((std::max)(src.rows(),src.cols())*2);
```

and afterwards, `temp` is moved to the actual destination. That means, prior reserving (and resizing) in your case does not help. I'm not sure though, why `temp` is not reserved to `nonZerosEstimate()` of the corresponding evaluator.

Independent of that, if you are working with `N x 1` sparse matrices you should consider switching to `SparseVector<double>` instead.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.

So in your opinion and experience, do you know of how could proceed without blowing out through all my memory ? My matrices are not always N X 1. Hence, I choose to use a column matrix as opposed to a sparse vector.

Comment: Did you try patching your local Eigen installation with `temp.reserve(src.nonZeroEstimate());` instead of the line I quoted?

Comment: I didn't want to mess with the source code. I ended up using .squeeze functionality after the sparse matrix operations to control the memory usage.